# ArrowFunctionExpr not found in @angular/compiler

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm using Angular CLI: 17.0.7 & Node: 20.10.0 in our angular application. The application used to run when it was set up 2 years ago. I'm trying to run the same application now, by installing all the js packages by running NPM INSTALL.

When I try to start the angular application, I get an error

> ---

An unhandled exception occurred: Named export 'ArrowFunctionExpr' not found. The requested module '@angular/compiler' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from '@angular/compiler';
const { ArrowFunctionExpr, LiteralArrayExpr, LiteralExpr: LiteralExpr2, literalMap, WrappedNodeExpr: WrappedNodeExpr3 } = pkg;

---

I'm not using ArrowFunctionExpr anywhere directly in our application and the correct angular packages should have installed (based on package.json) when I ran npm install. I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Could someone help me to understand the issue?

Comment: Please do `npm i -g @angular/core@17.0.7` to ensure that angular if already installed has the same version as the cli!